# monacaIDEへのビデオファイルのアップロード

Tags: monaca

monacaIDEへのビデオファイルのアップロードで
ファイルサイズの制限とか、総使用領域容量の制限とかあるのでしょうか？
ビデオ動画を使ったハウツーアプリを考えています

Comment: どの程度の大きさのファイルをアップロードするのでしょうか？